# I had taken 2 button hindi and english..on click of the button it change to other button

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle abc" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="horo_hindi btn btn-primary active">
<input type="radio" name="language" value="en">English</label><label class="horo_hindi btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="language" value="hi"  checked=""> Hindi</label> </div>
```

After this I have to set this things into `localStorage`. This is what I have tried:

```
var mylanguage=getUrlParameter('language');
localStorage.setItem('language',mylanguage);
```

after this I have too get data using Accept-Language, so I had done like this

```
headers: {
      authorization: "Basic " + btoa(c + ":" + d),
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept-Language":"en"
},
```

I am getting problem to get the data. How can I get the data using `localStorage.getitem`?

Comment: var myLanguage = localstorage.getitem('language')

Comment: sir..i had tried this for getting the data....but i got some error is that "mylanguage is not defined"..."Accept-Language":localStorage.getItem('language',mylanguage)